# Trying to remove "FDisk_partition_schem" from USB drive

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, usb

I'm trying to reset this USB drive so that I can use the 64.2 GB of space.
I've tried diskutil unmount and it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: a few more details would be good. What happens if youtry and delete the partition in Disk Utility? Or just format it as HFS+ or APFS?

Comment: The "FDisk_partition_scheme" isn't really taking up space, it's indicating that you have a 64.2GB disk formatted with the "FDisk" (aka MBR) partition scheme. The space *within* that is available for use as volumes, but most of it is empty. Mind you, you might want to switch to a different partition scheme (probably GPT), but then it's going to say "`GUID_partition_scheme *64.2 GB`".

Answer (score 0):

I fiqured it out. I used this:

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ Emptied /dev/disk3
```